# binning data points using statistics calculated on each subset - no looping challenge

Tags: r, loops, statistics, subset

With the help of stackoverflow, I have produced a dataset of paired x and y values, each with a site identifier. I need to subset by site(easy), and then bin the points based on their x values and calculate the means of x and y for each bin.

The trick is that the bins need to a) cover at least 1% of the logarithmic range of x (easy) and b) be large enough that the standard error of y is less than 1/2 of the mean of y for that bin.

In practice, I'd like to start at the largest value of x, set the bin range to 1% of the log(x) range, and then expand it if necessary until the error condition is met. The next bin would then start where the first left off and would be sized the same way, and so on.

sample data generator:

```
x <- runif(200,0,1)
y <- x + rnorm(200,0,0.1)
df <- data.frame(site=factor(c(rep("EBT",100), rep("MUT",100))),x,y
```

Thanks for any help, I'm definitely exploring the frontiers of what I can do in R.

I'm trying to follow [this analysis](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1029/2008WR006912/full), in case anyone is wondering what the point is

EDIT: I haven't written a loop to do this, but in pseudo-pseudo-code I think I'd try:

```
set minimum bin width  
start at the largest x value  
set the bin width to the minimum  
if stderr(y) < (mean(y) / 2)  
  calculate and store mean x and mean y  
otherwise extend bin by one data point and repeat  
next bin starts at first x following last bin  
repeat bin calculations until last bin runs into 0  
then combine final partial bin with previous complete bin and recalculate means
```

I'm happy taking a swing with some looping, but in the past things I thought had to be done that way ended up taking just a few lines of more elegant code, so I thought I'd put it out there.

Comment: why the no-looping constraint? Feels like it would be best to come up with a workable solution first, then (if it's too slow or inelegant) look for vectorized and/or Rcpp-enhanced versions. Can you show what you've tried so far?

Comment: Ive been avoiding loops based on past experience and co-worker scorn. I haven't written one for this, but I'll add one in pseudo-code above.

Comment: show your co-workers Chapter 4 of the Inferno http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf ... it's good to vectorize *if you can*, but your problem statement above sounds a lot like a `while` loop embedded in a `for` loop to me ...

Comment: There are a few notes at https://github.com/hadley/devtools/wiki/Functionals#converting-loops-to-functionals-and-when-its-not-possible about when for loops are the natural solution.

Comment: Loops it is. Thanks all. Is there a way to clear this question if there are no 'answers' posted?